# How to rename multiple file names using unix command

Tags: unix, sed, command

I have a list of file name like

```
sam.txt
ron.txt
maria.txt
glory.txt
```

and i need to change that to different name without manually renaming the   filename

Is there a sed command to perform that?

Comment: what? please elaborate your question. Also, why sed? `sed` processes text, not files

Comment: How you want to rename? is there any prefix/suffix which you want to add to the existing names?

Comment: You may be interested in http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename/rename.PL . Debian-based distros come with it as part of the `perl` package.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/mv & new_&/e' file
```

Comment: cool! Might be good to explain that the `e` flag implies `e`xecution in `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
ls *.txt | xargs -i mv {} {}_<New >
```

Comment: Short and sweet. @Vishal  you could have added the -I as a comment here you really didn't add much to Mahesh's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.txt | xargs -I {} mv {} {}_<NEW>
```

using `I` switch